# iTextSharp image not showing in aws lambda for c#

Tags: c#, image, aws-lambda, itext

I'm adding an image to a iTextSharp pdf in this way:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 0F,0F, 0F, 0F);
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foo/bar.png");      
img.ScaleToFit(595, 120);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
doc.Open();
doc.Add(img);
doc.Close();
```

Then I convert it to `byte[]` and then to `base64 string`, so it can be handled by AWS API Gateway.

```
byte[] pdf = ms.ToArray();      

var headersDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headersDic.Add("Content-type", "application/pdf");
headersDic.Add("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=file.pdf");

return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
{
    Body = Convert.ToBase64String(pdf),
    IsBase64Encoded = true,
    Headers = headersDic,
    StatusCode = 200
};
```

But the image is not shown in the pdf, just an almost indistinguishable part of it, which is the line you can see here:

[image]

Any ideas? maybe the conversions to byte[] or base64 and to binary again are giving problems?

When I add text everything goes good.

Comment: Do you get any solution?